# Accessing Uza's global object from an loaded external swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, external, global

I am using the 1.2 version of Uza's Global singleton (http://www.uza.lt/codex/as3-global-object/). The container swf stores some data and a link to a function in the "global" object.

Then another swf is loaded inside the container, it gets it's global instance with Global.getInstance();, and i suppose i can access the data and function stored in global by the container swf.

This works perfectly on localhost served by a webserver, but when i put the files on my external production server the loaded swf's global appears to not have anything stored by the container.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, looks like updating to Global 2.0 fixed this problem